# program that send wtsp message

Tags: python, api, automation, whatsapp

I'm trying to create a python program that checks a condition for example if the room temperature is above 20 degrees and informs the user by sending a WhatsApp message. the program will be on the user's computer and it's not necessary to have the wtsp account on it. I found a lot of sites that do this thing like *nexmo* but they are paid. I wanna know how to send the wtsp message but free.

Comment: What is your question about this program?

Comment: I wanna know how to send the wtsp message but free